# Java portability different OS/JDK

Tags: operating-system, java, portability

I am new on "java world" so I need to know the basics about portability in different OS and JDK. What I am seeing in internet is that if a compile a program on JDK 1.7, it will run on any JDK version >= 1.7, is it right? Thanks, and my apologies about my english it is not my default language.

Comment: "Roughly." You'll run into the (relatively few) inconsistencies when you do. The most common issue I recall is `new String(byte[])` (and a few similar) that use the "platforms default charset". Just go for it. When you run into an issue ... well, that'd make more of an interesting question.

Answer (score 1):

there is a option in java **-target version**
it says that...

```
Generate class files that target a specified version of the VM. Class files will run 
on the specified target and on later versions, but not on earlier versions of the VM.
Valid targets are 1.1, 1.2, 1.3,1.4, 1.5 (also 5), 1.6 (also 6), and 1.7 (also 7).  

       If -source is not specified, the value of -target is 1.7  
       If -source is 1.2, the value of -target is 1.4  
       If -source is 1.3, the value of -target is 1.4  
       If -source is 1.5, the value of -target is 1.7  
       If -source is 1.6, the value of -target is 1.7 
       For all other values of -source, the value of -target is the value of -source.
```

so " if a compile a program on JDK 1.7, it will run on any JDK version >= 1.7, is  right"

Comment: Which will also require `-source` and `-bootclasspath` options specified.  Fortunately the Java 7 SDK finally warns of `source`/`target` without `bootclasspath`.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. Most of what you write will automatically work in any (version compatible) JVM. I moved an significant Java Swing GUI application from Windows to Linux, and I only had to change the config files to point to different directories. It just works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, unless something deprecated in newer versions. Deprecation may result in some inconsistence.